# Assign values to random cells in raster

Tags: raster, assign

I was wondering if there is a way to assign a value to a predetermined number of cells at random locations within a raster?

For example, if I wanted to assign

1. a value of '10' to 3 cells at random locations for cells with a value of '1' in a raster
2. a value of '20' to 4 cells at random locations for cells with a value of '1' in a raster
3. a value of '40' to 10 cells at random locations for cells with a value of '1' in a raster

What is the best way to do this? And, are there any examples/scripts that already exist?

For example the original raster below:
[image]

and the output:
[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

All sorted now :)

```
c = np.random.random((10,10)).round(0).astype(int)
c_idx = np.arange(c.size)[c.flatten()==1]
np.random.shuffle(c_idx)
d = c.flatten()
d[c_idx[:3]] = 10
d[c_idx[3:7]] = 20
d[c_idx[7:17]] = 40
d = d.reshape(c.shape)
d
```